# Postgres/postgis st_makepoint

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, coordinates

I am looping through a csv, taking latlng values and trying to add there geometry to postgis enabled postgres table. xy values are int's

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("connected")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE test pt_geom geometry);''')
conn.commit()
for row in csvfile:#sample code
    x = row[0]
    y = row[1]#etc...
    xy = (x, y)#tuple of the int xy's
    cur.execute('''insert into test
                        (pt_geom) values
                        (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(%s,%s),4326));''', (xy))
    conn.commit()
```

the script is running, connecting to the db, creating the table inserting the latlng but the values are coming up in a strange text format-I am not sure why that is..I have not found any info on this yet on the web. possible solutions? readsoning? the xy is an int value. is it spatially displayed? does the %s convert it to a string...anything would be helpful

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `WKB` format wichs is a binary representation of the geometry. To select the geometry in `GeoJSON` format for example you can use : [ST_AsGeoJSON()](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html)

Comment: so the geometry xy locations are good?

Comment: There's no reason to think are bad, use the function I say in my edited answer and check if the point are the ones you tried to insert from your CSV.

Comment: do i use  ST_AsGeoJSON to create the table or when i use the insert method?

Comment: No, you should use in SELECT query to select the point of the table in this format. The "geometry" data type stores the geometry in WKB, so that is what you see when you use SELECT pt_geom from test. What i'm suggesting you is SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(pt_geom) FROM test.

Comment: Also, if you want the INSERT Query to Return the inserted points (With GeoJSON format) in the same query you can do :  insert into test
                        (pt_geom) values
                        (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(%s,%s),4326)) returning ST_AsGeoJSON(pt_geom);

Comment: okay thanks il give that a try-a few hours knew to postgres..

Comment: awesome it works- another question..can i have 2 set geometry points on the same table? ex. pt_geom1 and pt_geom2 in separate columns? or should I just make a separate table for each?

Comment: Yes, you can have more than one geometry column and giving indexes and contraints for each geometry colum. =)

Answer (score 2):

The result is in geometry format. You could see the coordinates of that point by adding `st_astext(geom)` function while selecting.

```
select st_astext(geometry_column) from table_name;
```